# what if i never call unregisterReceiver method for BroadcastReceivers?

Tags: android

it will stop when app closed or stop when the Device booted or it will work till the app uninstalled

i am writing app which contain BroadcastReceiver to receive Google Cloud Message (GCM)

and i need the receive to work all the time even when the app is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the Broadcast Receiver to your Manifest

Example :
  [Boardcast Receiver Manifest](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/03/android-broadcast-receiver-in-detail.html#.U2k-I_l_uBo)